# Blazor WASM - Custom procedures in app initialization/load

Tags: blazor, webassembly

In my Blazor WASM application I want to dynamically load additional stylesheets and scripts that are provided through dependency injection. I don't want to manually add these to the plain index.html and upon initializing the app it is too late. I want to include this process into the procedure while blazor is loading from 0-100% before the app starts.

Is there any way to put custom tasks into the lifecycle of blazor while it is initializing itself from `\_framework/blazor.webassembly.js`?

Comment: I don't think you can, because before the blazor starts you don't have access to di container.